# How to set font to the one that a user chose using font chooser?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I want to set the font of a [GtkTextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html) to the one that a user chose using [GtkFontChooserDialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFontChooserDialog.html). How can this be done? I've tried many ways but none of them work good enough or at all.

Also, I use GTK+3 stable, so please do not recommend deprecated solutions (e.g. using [gtk_widget_override_font()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-font)). I want an up-to-date solution to this problem, I already know how to solve it using deprecated functions.

---

I tried GtkTextTag just like [theGtknerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6150775/thegtknerd) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383052/how-to-set-font-to-the-one-that-a-user-chose-using-font-chooser/52397282#52397282).

There are two problems with this method:

1. This doesn't change the style context of the widget, through which I get the current font.
2. I used [gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-apply-tag) to apply the tag that contains the font that a user chose, but this isn't *dynamic*, the font is changed only between the current start and the current end, which doesn't take into the account the later potential modifications to the text.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use [GtkTextTag](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextTag.html) like a Google search brought up [here](http://www.bravegnu.org/gtktext/x113.html).

Your other option is to use CSS, but I don't think it will be very friendly for formatting a lot of text.

Comment: I know, my current solution is to format the text given by `gtk_font_chooser_get_font()` to CSS and I almost did succeed to make it work, but some fonts (e.g. _B&H LucidaBright_) just won't work and I also don't know how to deal with weird text styles like _Sans_, _Book_ and _Initials_.

Comment: Seems that your solution doesn't work (or I don't know how to do it) after all. See my edited question.

Answer (score -1):

Use GtkTextTag like this:

```
gtk_text_buffer_create_tag(buffer, "font", "family", "Monospace", NULL);

...

GtkTextIter start;
GtkTextIter end;

gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &start);
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &end);

gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag_by_name(text_buffer, "font", &start, &end);
```

And you can use `gtk_widget_modify_font(GtkWidget*, PangoFontDescription*)`. But it's very obsolete, and doesn't have effect in some time.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but I explicitly said _please do not recommend deprecated solutions_.